# VB.Net Xpath Error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have xml data with node name as a numeric value and i need to retrieve the node with that name.

when i use the below code it throws the exception
"Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

Code:

```
`lSampleXml.SelectSingleNode("//" & lClass.Name)`
```

where lClass.Name is a numeric value = 6556 casted into string.

Please help to get rid of the exception.

Sample XML :

```
<Root>
   <6556>
     <Data> </Data>
     <Text> </Text>
   </6556>
   <1223>
   </1223>
   <Phone>
   </Phone>
</Root>
```

Comment: I guess the backticks don't belong to your first line of code?

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to load that XML in an `XmlDocument` object - I cannot event get to call `SelectSingleNode()`. This is expected: the XML is not valid. Are you sure you are loading that XML? Can we see the code you use to load `lSampleXml`?

Answer (score 3):

Well an XML name (like an element name or attribute name) can't start with a digit so having `<6556>...</6556>` is not possible as well-formed XML and thus a path expression `//6556` as well is not meaningful as a way to select elements of that name.

So you should get an error when trying to parse your markup sample.

Comment: we used another approach, i used .NET serializer to convert it into XML for me.. !! thanks ...